# HAProxy goes to the same website even though they have different sub-domains

Tags: reverse-proxy, haproxy

I have an issue with HAProxy where it goes to the same website even though they have different sub-domains.

For example, I go to foo.domain.com then on another tab I go to bar.domain.com and another tab for baz.domain.com, all three loads the foo.domain.com website and when I hard refresh the other sites it goes properly to the proper website then it happens again making the new website the face of all domains unless I keep refreshing the websites.

I have the following configuration:

```
defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  tcplog
        option  dontlognull
        retries 3
        option  redispatch
        maxconn 30000
        timeout connect 10s
        timeout client 60s
        timeout server 60s

frontend http_in
        mode http
        option httplog
        bind *:80
        option forwardfor
 
        acl host_foo hdr(host) -i foo.domain.com 
        acl host_bar hdr(host) -i bar.domain.com
        acl host_baz hdr(host) -i baz.domain.com

        use_backend http_foo if host_foo
        use_backend http_bar if host_bar
        use_backend http_baz if host_baz

backend http_foo
        mode http
        option httplog
        option forwardfor
        server foo foo:80

backend http_bar
        mode http
        option httplog
        option forwardfor
        server bar bar:80
    
backend http_baz
        mode http
        option httplog
        option forwardfor
        server baz baz:80

frontend https_in
        mode tcp
        option tcplog
        bind *:443
        acl tls req.ssl_hello_type 1
        tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
        tcp-request content accept if tls

        acl host_foo req.ssl_sni -i foo.domain.com
        acl host_bar req.ssl_sni -i bar.domain.com
        acl host_baz req.ssl_sni -i baz.domain.com
        
        use_backend https_foo if host_foo
        use_backend https_bar if host_bar
        use_backend https_baz if host_baz

backend https_foo
        mode tcp
        option tcplog
        option ssl-hello-chk
        server foo foo:443

backend https_bar
        mode tcp
        option tcplog
        option ssl-hello-chk
        server bar bar:443

backend https_baz
        mode tcp
        option tcplog
        option ssl-hello-chk
        server baz baz:443
```

I'm using HAProxy version 2.4.12. Is there anything to do to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the host header, something like within HTTP mode:

```
backend https_baz
    mode http
    option ssl-hello-chk
    reqirep ^Host: Host:\ baz.domain.com
    server baz baz:443
```